# Is this sufficient to sanitise a user supplied SQL query?

Tags: sql

I want to allow SELECT queries to my database, but do not want to allow updates (or drops!).

Is it sufficient to ensure the query starts with SELECT and does not contain a semicolon?

I am using jdbc to execute the query, currently against MySQL, but hope not to limit it to that.

Edit:
I appreciate the caution of using a user who cannot update, but want to know if that is necessary, rather than just superstitious.

Comment: Probably not. You should manage this through only giving `SELECT` permissions. Please state RDBMS though.

Comment: That is a security desaster waiting to happen - IF you really must allow SQL queries then execute them via a special user which has the least needed privileges possible!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to go about this is to create a new account and allow the account certain commands.

Comment: That won't help.  I can crash a server with only `USAGE` privilege if you let me run a SELECT query of my choosing.

Answer (score 1):

You must not execute code submitted by users.  Allowing users to submit code is a great way to open yourself up to a denial of service attack, at the very least.  For example, an attacker could easily submit a query with a huge Cartesian product guaranteed to bring down your server.

You can safely allow users to specify *values*, but not code.  Then combine the values they enter into your SQL queries by using prepared statements with parameters.

Allowing users to submit SQL queries is as dangerous as `shellexec($_GET["cmd"]);`

Comment: Thanks Bill, however the question is trying to get to exactly how this is dangerous. DOS is something I can live with, I am scared of data deletion or compromise.